# How do I double the size of an image on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, scaling

I have an image, say 320 x 240 pixels in size, which I want to display doubled in size (i.e. 640 x 480 pixels) on a web page. In the past, I have done this by setting `width=640` on the `img` tag.

However, I have just spotted the following [in the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/semantics-embedded-content.html#sec-dimension-attributes):

> The dimension attributes are not intended to be used to stretch the image.

In that case, how do I double the size of an image on a web page without going against what the spec intends?

Comment: they're saying if you have an image of 320px you shouldn't blow it up twice.

Comment: @JoeWarner: No, the attributes are there to tell the layout engine how big the image is prior to download, so the page doesn't move around as images appear. Stretching is a byproduct of lying about it / getting it wrong. :-)

Comment: Double it server side. And ask for my server/resources/my resource?w=x&h=y. Cache it somehow or hide it behind a CDN. Otherwise you will have rendering issues, stretch/resize issues and so on

Comment: Looking at the following might help. W3 suggests using flex, flexbox.. https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Apr/0719.html and https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/Kgofa

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use CSS instead. The two methods that jump to mind are using the width or [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) transformation.

E.g. `img { width: 640px; }`. This will keep the proper aspect ratio without specifying the height.

```css
img {
  width: 640px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/320x240">
```

E.g. `img { transform: scale(2) }`

```css
img {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/320x240">
```

Answer (score 8):

You can set the dimension of the parent image container

```css
.imageContainer {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="imageContainer">

  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQqdnZQDnZOOyBGXXB23WS87IAxZ85drC-ylgrqWCqYk2aEh3Vo">
</div>
```

Comment: Is this approach (using a container) better than just setting `width: 640px; height: 480px;` directly on the `img`?

Comment: this causes the image to stretch with width 100% and height 100%.  If your image is 200px X 500px and you set it to 640px X 480px container your image gets squished and if you do it to a larger container where the height is say 1000px the image stretches.

Answer (score 5):

Via CSS, ideally in a style sheet, but in the `style` attribute if necessary.

For instance, here's your 32x32 gravatar stretched to 128x128:

```css
.stretch-128 {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6b938dc4205cd0cea4e4e68451c42a21?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" class="stretch-128">
```

Naturally, any time you stretch an image like that, the quality is likely to suffer.

Answer (score 3):

First I created a div with a class named divWrapper with a specific size.  We then create a class for our image with a width of 100%(which spans across the divWapper), and added a height of auto(To automatically keep the height in proper proportion). You can adjust the size of the image according to the divWapper class.

```css
.divWrapper{
width:640px;
height:480px;
float:left;
}
//Now set you image class to 
.imageclass{  
width:100%
height:auto;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="divWrapper">
<image class="imageclass" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2d/Picea_glauca_taiga.jpg">
<div>
```

This will keep the image in proportion no matter what size the wrapper container is.

### A Helpful Note:

You must have a high quality image from the start I suggest using vector images. I prefer to Use PNG or SVG. It has better quality than jpeg and others. 
Here are a couple of link that describes a little about image extensions.

https://blog.online-convert.com/best-image-file-extensions/

https://www.sitepoint.com/gif-png-jpg-which-one-to-use/

Comment: actually setting it to 100% height would stretch to fit  and degrade the image.  If you must work with height set the height to the size and the width to auto. and OP hasn't commented about the float.

Comment: Definitely, you are right about it. Although, the question is about `double the size of an image`. In order to achieve this, it would cost stretching issues, but we don't know what he needs to do.

I don't know if there is something in between. If you know a solution; Please share it with us!

Comment: @Elharony  This solution scales to the proper dimensions and keeps the same ratio as the original. If you double the width of the image container the image doubles... Why are we having this dialog anyway is their a problem with my solution?

Comment: Oh, no there is no problem here. My concern here is all about the fixed value for the parent: `width:640px; height:480px;`. I mean, we don't know the incoming image's size. Ex; If the original image was 400x200. To double it, we wanted to set the parent div to 800x400. Not 640x480. That what was in my mind while trying to provide a javascript - dynamic - solution. But I guess it is all up to the needs of the one who asked this question. Anyways, I liked your solution and there is nothing wrong with it at all, I am just sharing my thought out loud with you!

Comment: This is an example OP will know the size as he builds his page.  Doesn't really matter the size of the image just what you do with it.  He has to put the image somewhere, in some container.  I like your js solution but even that has to be placed inside of some container or tag.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. Thanks for having such a discussion, this helped me to write to-the-point answers here on SOF, I am a bit new and this helped me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 4 ways to do this.

### 1. directly set `width` attribute of `img`

principle: modify the width of the image.

set `width: 640px; display: block` for the `img` tag.

### 2. wrap `img` with a `div`

principle: inherit the width from parent node.

1. div `width: 640px`
2. img `display: block; width: 100%`

### 3. set the image as background of a `div`

principle: the image is no longer a `img` tag, but the background of a node.

1. div `background-image: url()`, use the image as background image.
2. div `background-size: {2x width} {2x height}`, to resize the size of the image

### 4. scale the image into 2x

1. set the `transform` property to `scale(2)`, which means I want the size of it 2 times of its original size

tips: also, we need to set the property `transform-origin` into `top left`, in order that it can start from the position(relatively) `top: 0; left: 0;`

Run the snippet and have a look :)

```css
.method-1 {
  display: block;
  width: 640px;
}

.method-2 {
  width: 640px;
}
.method-2 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.method-3 {
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/320x240);
  background-size: 640px 480px;
}

.method-4 {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<h1>method 1: img displays as block, width 640px</h1>
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/320x240" class="method-1" />

<br/>

<h1>method 2: parent dom width 640px, img width 100%.</h1>
<div class="method-2">
  <img src="http://www.placehold.it/320x240" />
</div>

<br/>

<h1>method 3: the img as div's background, use the background-size attribute to set 2x size.</h1>
<div class="method-3"></div>

<br/>

<h1>method 4: use CSS3 transform property to scale the image into 2x.</h1>
<p>tips: when we set `transform: scale(2);`, we also need to define the `transform-origin` property to `top left`, in order that the image will align from top to bottom as well as from left to right, or it will lost itself. LOL.</p>
<img src="http://www.placehold.it/320x240" class="method-4" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of things you want to avoid when loading an image:

- [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content) - which happens when the browser does not have the image size before loading it (in which case it doesn't allocate any space for it until it's fully loaded) or telling the browser the wrong size
- distortion (displaying an image at a different aspect ratio than 1:1)
- pixelation (displaying an image at a significantly bigger size than its native size)
- loading images with significantly bigger native size than the size in page - they slow the page down and consuming unnecessary bandwidth

There are ways to deal with each of the above.

For avoiding **FOUC**, there are a few methods:

- have the image sizes (or ratio) saved, besides the file itself, so you can allocate the correct space in page flow, before loading the images (WP does this out of the box, for example and most themes use it to avoid FOUC)
- have the image load in a container, as background image with `background-size: cover`, so FOUC is not possible, as the document already knows the size of the element, before the image is loaded. This technique also has the advantage of not displaying broken image anchors when an image fails to load. Also, this technique is widely used today in full screen image layouts, some of them using parallax effect. Has the disadvantage of cropping top/bottom or left/right, depending on aspect ratio difference between container and image.
- load the image in a `position:absolute` centered container and when you have its size (and are able to calculate exact position in document flow) animate its scale from 0 to 1 while also animating its container size from "default" to proper size.

Regarding **distortion**, there isn't much to say, except do not do it. Any other option is better than distortion: cropping, pixelation, even FOUC. Distortion basically says: *"Don't trust me with design tasks - I'm unable to tell does from donts"* - which, to many, translates to: *"I'm unqualified for professional frontend development. I'll mess up any website coming my way, most likely without knowing"*.

On **pixelation**. It's a tricky one: you want the page to load as fast as possible, but also want crisp images. When dealing with very large background images, a neat trick is to add a pattern over the image (stripes, dots or any other such semi-transparent patterns - an artistic touch to make pixellation a lot less noticeable).

Another good and smart technique for getting best of both worlds (speed and image quality) is to:

- load a proportional thumbnail versions for every image below the fold (yes, they'll look pixelated) and display them at `.65` opacity. Lazy load the full size images before they are scrolled into view. Even if the  pixelated version is visible for a short while, it will be replaced by the full-size one, creating a focus-in effect, together with changing opacity to `1`. If you have quality, outstanding images, you really want this effect (a) because it makes them stand out and b) because you want to load the images at proper, crisp size). The images will look "alive" and get subtle focus, leaving visitors with the impression of looking at a highly sophisticated website.

Avoid **oversizing**. Here `src-set` comes into play, combined with the thumbnail loaders described above. And, of course: lazy-loading. Always lazy load anything below the fold. It makes a big difference.

In short, that's how you correctly load images. In reality, it's a huge subject, I haven't even touched optimization, raster vs vectors, svg's or webp formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by two way as below.

```
<img class="xx" src="http://placehold.jp/150x150.png">

.xx {
zoom: 200%;
}
.xx {
 transform: scale(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally I haven't found an article providing a way to scale images with client side technologies (leave it the [browser's mechanism](http://entropymine.com/resamplescope/notes/browsers/)) without losing some quality.

With that being said I am afraid that If you want the best way to double your image according to [HTML Standard specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#adaptive-images) the best answer is to use a different image. A scaled up image through back-end process or through Photoshop. Now if you want adaptive image according to the user's screen since most probably this is the actual case the HTML Standard to achieve that is with the following way:

```
<picture>
 <source srcset="http://www.placehold.it/320x240" media="(min-width: 600px)">
 <source srcset="http://www.placehold.it/640x480" media="(min-width: 900px)">
 <img src="http://www.placehold.it/160x120">
</picture>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding `<img srcset="">` to your answer?  `<picture>` is not always the best way to go.  [Don’t use <picture> (most of the time) ](https://cloudfour.com/thinks/dont-use-picture-most-of-the-time/#comment-1355)

Answer (score 0):

Out of my experience the best way to double the size of any image for usage in websites is to actually double the image in a program like Photoshop and then upload it. 
The image size, the pixel density for the retina screens, and the plethora of different screen sizes makes working with images a little more advanced than it used to be, but nothing too hard.

check the following example:

```html
<picture>
  <source
    sizes="(width < 32em) contain, (width >=32em) contain 80vw calc(100vh - 10em)"
    srcset="full.jpg 2048h 1024w, half.jpg 1024h, quarter.jpg 512h, eighth.jpg 256h" />
  <img src="eighth.jpg" alt="rose flower!" />
</picture>
```

You upload a relatively big image, at least FHD, or bigger, and then with the 'sizes' and 'srcset' you configure it, which one to load depending on the screen size/type. 
This way you cover any potential resolution, small or big, and you always display the best version of your image.
Ok, i admit it, there is some manual labor work to happen in every image prior the uploading, but the final result is worth it!

Now if you insist of keeping the same small image file and double it via using coding, then the best way is to add a CSS class to your image, and on that class specify your doubled dimensions, and that's it.

Here is a funny and good explanation about images srcset, sizes, and the importance of why we need to do it this way.
[A fun article on srcset](http://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/)

Answer (score 0):

You can user javascript for like this way this to change image size by it's double

[Check this JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rj_Innocenr_Coder/ygt5hweL)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
    var img = $("#sky");
    // Create dummy image to get real size
    $("<img>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function(){
        var realWidth = this.width;
        var realHeight = this.height;
        alert("Original width=" + realWidth + ", " + "Original height=" +     realHeight);
        var newWidth = realWidth * 2;
        var newHeight = realHeight * 2;
        $("#sky").width(newWidth);
        $("#sky").width(newHeight);
         alert("new Image Size" + newWidth+"x"+newHeight);
    });
});   
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://www.cluedin.net/images/providers/stackoverflow.png" id="sky" width="250" alt="Cloudy Sky" contextmenu="skymenu">
    <p><button type="button">Get Original Image Size And Double it</button></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that many various ways. But whatever you do, first download your image which size you want it to mean the double size otherwise if you double the size, then it gets pixelated or looks faded.

```
  image{ transform: scale(2); }
```

1. **Try transform scale to double sized your image**
2. **Try setting the width in the image with CSS**
3. **Try with JavaScript with setAttribute("width", "size")**

Answer (score 0):

I like most of the previous solutions, but the issue here is that we don't actually know the current image size to double it!!

So, my solution is kinda dynamic, and it won't affect other images on your website as well.
Also, it can be enhanced to `triple` their sizes, and more if you wanted!

> Check a [Live Preview here](https://jsfiddle.net/p2hb772L/2/).

Or read it below:

#### HTML

```
<img class="resize-double" src="https://placeimg.com/100/50/nature">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/200/100/nature">
```

#### JavaScript

```
// Select all images to be resized
const toResizeImgs = document.querySelectorAll(".resize-double");

// Loop over those images and double their size
for(let i=0; i < toResizeImgs.length; i++) {
  toResizeImgs[i].style.width = toResizeImgs[i].offsetWidth * 2 + "px";
  toResizeImgs[i].style.height = toResizeImgs[i].offsetHeight + "px";
}
```

It would select the images with the class `resize-double`, loop on them and change their width/height to 2x of the current one!

***NOTE:** Both`offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` return the current width/height including Margins, Paddings and Borders. If it doesn't suit you, you can use `clientWidth` and `clientHeight`, or even `scrollWidth` and `scrollHeight` based on your needs!*

Comment: Hmmm, I noticed a downvote. Can the one who downvoted me, help me out by explaining why. That would help me to improve my answers next time!

Thanks :)

Comment: Wasn't me, but it's probably because you're using JS where a CSS-only solution would be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @mrcharlie! But the issue with the CSS Solutions that we don't actually know the original image size. That's why I thought JS Solution would be better as it would double its original size whatever it was.

Comment: You don't need to know the original image size, you only want to scale up the image size. Using something like `transform: scale(2)` would work.

Comment: @mrcharlie though this can be done with CSS the OP has Javascript tagged so a JS answer is fine.  One of the reasons i like StackOverflow there are always several ways to do things and each way can be correct this is coding :)

Comment: @Jonny, I'm not the one that downvoted, I'm just hypothesizing ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @mrcharlie No i didnt say that i was just reading the comments'

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal way is to load the **biggest image** to your site and **downscale** it where you need through *CSS*.

1) Best quality for your image since upscaling distorts the image.

2) No need to load more images with different sizes

3) Downscaling does not spoil the image and it is just some lines of *CSS*

If you don't want to load the bigger image, the second best and fastest solution is to upscale it through CSS. Width attribute no longer works in `<img>`

Answer (score 0):

### CSS trick, setting just one property

If you want to use CSS, there's a really good way:

```
img#image_id {
    width: calc(2 * 320px);
    height: auto; /* This can be omitted */
}
```

This is very useful which you can change the scale of the image by changing just one number (i.e. the factor). No worries about the image height, it will be set automatically by the browser, even if you omit setting image height to auto (because auto is the default value of width and height; see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)). Also, you can set height instead of setting width.

It would be useful for responsive design in a way, and I think it's really tricky!

**Note**: It doesn't work with flex-boxes, if you set the parent's width or height. In this case, you must explicitly set width and height, or there would be another tricks for that; flex-boxes works completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use css and avoid stretching.

```
img{ width:640px; background-size: cover; height:auto;}
```

This will stretch your image equally with suitable height. You can also try setting height to a specific number.

Answer (score 0):

> The dimension attributes are not intended to be used to stretch the image.

As you already mentioned that using width attribute doesn't intend to stretch the image. so in that case we should use `transform: scale(2);` which is a good idea but this may also get conflict regarding image overlapping other content, so best idea is to use 2x width of div with image scaled 2x with css property '`transform: scale(2);`'

**Hence:** using the below style should be a good idea.

```
.img2x_container {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
}

.img2x_container img {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

> This use case is only beneficial when we know the image height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of transform -> scale

```
img#imagId {
    -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(2); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use following Java Script code to scale image according which can fit best in container. You may make few changes per your need.

```
function scaleImage(container, image) {
var c = document.getElementById(container);
var i = document.getElementById(image);
var newSize = scaleSize(c.clientWidth, c.clientHeight, i.width, i.height);
i.style.width = newSize.width;
i.style.height = newSize.height;
c.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
c.style.border = "none";
var intHeight = ((100-((parseFloat(i.style.height)/87)*100))/2);
var strHeightPercentage = intHeight.toString().concat("%");
c.style.top = strHeightPercentage;}
```

function scaleSize(maxW, maxH, currW, currH) {
    var ratio = currH / currW;

```
if (currW >= maxW && ratio <= 1) {
    currW = maxW;
    currH = currW * ratio;
}
else if (currH >= maxH) {
    currH = maxH;
    currW = currH / ratio;
}
return { width: currW, height: currH };
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The most complex stuffs are hidden in the simplest!

What they mean *to me* by this sentence is to «take care of scalability».

And for that, there is nothing better than **svg**. We need to think about caching. Just avoid to embed them directly. Let the client browser do the caching by using external **src**.

As soon as this is well done, we can scale it at *moon size*, keeping it smooth...

**Svg** can be generated server side, but it's always better to carefully create them with (gimp). Then open the svg with a text editor.

If using images, currently, for nice rendering in different screen resolution, the best should be to use a set of them in different resolution, with `srcset`. Finally just like other dynamics elements, let the client browser do the choice by providing him many options. Again, with caching in mind. it will download and keep only the one it need.

If an html solution exist, we should use it before trying to alter it (by js or css).

https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-css/

A new *css property* is in town: **image-rendering**.

[image]

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#the-image-rendering

As usual, the most complete answer are the specs!

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3